# Asan: stack-use-after-return: want to learn more about the `Shadow bytes around the buggy address:` and how to access it

Tags: c, clang, address-sanitizer

Here's a minimal example of how I'm rasing the `stack-use-after-return` error:

```cpp
int *ptr; // global definition
// stack allocate and initialize`ptr` 
void alloc() {
  int local[10];
  ptr = &local[0];
}
// make a `return`
int ret_after_use() {
    return ptr[10];
}
int main() {
  alloc();
  int i = ret_after_use();
  ptr = &i; // error: use after return
  return 0;
}
```

As expected, Asan catches this problem and raises the following message (raw) -

```
=================================================================
==1011387==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-return on address 0x7f3ada500048 at pc 0x564ebacaa22c bp 0x7ffe3f0635d0 sp 0x7ffe3f0635c8
READ of size 4 at 0x7f3ada500048 thread T0
    #0 0x564ebacaa22b in ret_after_use /home/aissy/c_cpp/understanding/UBs/stack_use_after_return.c:17:9
    #1 0x564ebacaa4c9 in main /home/aissy/c_cpp/understanding/UBs/stack_use_after_return.c:31:11
    #2 0x7f3adc23c78f in __libc_start_call_main /usr/src/debug/glibc-git/glibc/csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:16
    #3 0x7f3adc23c849 in __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 /usr/src/debug/glibc-git/glibc/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:360:3
    #4 0x564ebabad084 in _start /home/aissy/aur/glibc-git/src/glibc/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:115

Address 0x7f3ada500048 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 72 in frame
    #0 0x564ebacaa04f in alloc /home/aissy/c_cpp/understanding/UBs/stack_use_after_return.c:7

  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 72) 'local' (line 8) <== Memory access at offset 72 overflows this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-return /home/aissy/c_cpp/understanding/UBs/stack_use_after_return.c:17:9 in ret_after_use
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0fe7db497fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe7db497fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe7db497fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe7db497fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe7db497ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0fe7db498000: f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5[f5]f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5
  0x0fe7db498010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe7db498020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe7db498030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe7db498040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe7db498050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==1011387==ABORTING
```

The part I'm interested about is the `Shadow bytes around the buggy address:` part, particularly what I'm confused about is the addresses that are being shown here to indicate redzones, use-after-free etc. I don't understand where these addresses are coming from, nor how to read from those addresses in either my C program or a debugger like GDB.

I assume the block of memory or stack these addresses are referring to is not the address to the stack (by looking at `sp` and `bp`, they are not what it seems like).

Starting with the first of `stack-after-return` (`f5`), namely `0x0ffb70398000`, I want to know -
a) Where are these addresses coming from?
b) How to read from those addresses (the contents) in a debugger or my C program itself?

Comment: The `alloc()` function does illegal code. You store the address of internal data, when the function ends that data no more exists so `ptr` points on an invalid address.

Comment: @dalfaB yes, that's right! But I intentionally wanted it to be part of this way (also the example on the official Asan github page shows this example: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerExampleUseAfterReturn). I want this code to be intentionally buggy to raise errors by the sanitizers.

Comment: I suggest you read [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719265/20270), as well as [AddressSanitizerAlgorithm](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAlgorithm) which it links. As for the shadow bytes themselves, your program should never try to access these directly.

Comment: >  your program should never try to access these directly

is there any way to access it at all, any way perform IO to them?

Comment: You could print those out in gdb, figuring the addresses out as documented (or by using the API from gdb, e.g. calling `__asan_get_shadow_mapping`). You shouldn't modify the shadow mapping directly. Any attempt by instrumented code to access this _will_ result in a crash, so don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadow memory is a part of process address space and can be accessed via the following mapping:

```
addr -> shadow_start + (addr >> 3)
```

The value of `shadow_start` depends on the platform and can be located in [asan_mapping.h](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_mapping.h) header. In particular for x86_64 it's `0x00007fff8000`.

Each byte of shadow memory holds information about corresponding 8-byte double word in your program's memory. Asan displays it to you so that you are aware of the state of memory area which surrounds the problematic address.